# Number of 3-way contingency tables

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, polytopes

Denote by $f(n)$ the number of $2\times 2 \times 2$ contingency tables with all 2-dim marginals equal to $n$.  What is $f(n)$?

It is easy to see that  $f(n)$ is polynomial of degree 4, since it counts the number of integer points in a certain 4-dim polytope.  I am just curious to see it written explicitly.  Also, do you know of a reference where this polynomial is written?

P.S.  Even just the lead cofficient would be of interest, i.e. the volume of this polytope.

Comment: If you're sure it's a polynomial of degree 4, then it suffices to compute $f(x)$ for $x=0,1,2,3,4$.

Comment: Let $M$ be the contingency table. If $M_{111}=a,M_{121}=b,M_{211}=c,M_{221}=d,M_{112}=e,M_{122}=f,M_{212}=g,M_{222}=h$, by two dimensional marginals, you mean the sums $a+b+c+d,e+f+g+h,a+c+e+g,b+d+f+h,a+b+e+f,c+d+g+h$?

Comment: @talegari - Yes.